# If a company uses an idea from an online wishlist for a videogame can they be sued for copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright, ownership

I posted a very specific / blueprint idea for features in a videogame and the corporation 100% used it and made millions from it. This wasn't just 1 idea, this was a nearly 1000-word "blueprint" that got into the specifics of how it'd all work together. The link to the idea was also emailed to them well before they implemented it in the game, so they were aware of it.

Can they be sued for copyright infringement retroactively if the blueprint was posted publicly (and the link sent to them). Also this blueprint wasn't available anywhere else on the internet. .

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to protect my idea by copyright?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18530/how-to-protect-my-idea-by-copyright)

Comment: @Trish The word "idea" in this question is a red herring. The substance needs to be looked at.

Comment: What do you mean by a "blueprint"? A visual design? Architectural drawings are copyrightable but the design they represent isn't.

Answer (score 4):

### Ideas have no legal protection

Provided they didn’t breach the copyright in your words, they can take all the ideas they like.

Even a highly detailed "blueprint" or specification of gameplay elements is unlikely to be infringed by a game (or novel, or film) that fully implements the outline. When people submit such proposals, they usually seek contractual protections for their ideas because IP law doesn't cover them.

Comment: Why can't the game be derivative work from the blueprint? Why can't it be legally protected like movie scenarios/treatments are?

Comment: @Greendrake because ideas are UNCOPYRIGHTABLE

Comment: @Trish Who's talking about ideas? BLUEPRINT. Tell that to a movie screenplay writer whose work got stolen and a film was made based on it.

Comment: @Greendrake generally, yes, you can: you have to prove that the one that made the same thing actually **knew** about your thing, and a blueprint or rough outline is nothing but an idea - and unprotectable.

Comment: @Trish It appears to be a clear premise of the question that the company **knew** about the blueprint.

Comment: @Greendrake the plaintiff has the burden of proof for that. Defendant only needs to show on the balance of probabilities that they didn't know. E.g. Magic's head designer has publicly stated that it's WOTC policy for designers to stop reading an email if looks like a fan-made idea, presumably to maintain this defence. OP can't just say "I emailed them" or "I put it up online", they have to show that the game company read that email.

Comment: @Caleth No one says that the plaintiff does not have the burden of proof. That's not what the question is about.

Comment: @Greendrake "Can they be sued?" is *always* yes. "Can I expect to win a suit" or "Can I expect a suit to survive a motion for summary judgement" are more what people mean by that question.

Comment: @Caleth That's correct too. Do I contradict it anywhere?

Answer (score -3):

> can they be sued for copyright infringement?

Yes.

Although ideas are not copyrightable, blueprints are.

A game built on a blueprint is a derivative work based on it (analogous to [movies filmed based on a screenplay](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/101467/2682)).

The key issue would be to prove that the game developer indeed *used* the blueprint. Absent direct acknowledgment from them, this can potentially be proved by inference (e.g. based on reasonable unlikeliness that particular similarities were coincidental). It would be, however, up to the jury (or the judge in a bench trial) to draw that inference. They have 100% discretion to draw or not to draw it (which means they could potentially accept a bribe from the game developer to *not* draw it).