# What legal protection is there for movie screenplays/treatments?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Bob writes a movie screenplay (or a "treatment", meaning a detailed plot/screenplay approximation) and sends it to a movie studio which in turn makes a movie based on the screenplay or treatment.

Is that movie a derivative work? Is Bob's work legally protected anyhow (absent a contract)?

Answer (score 2):

### Clear cut Copyright infringement

By being given a screenplay, **reading and using it**, Rob made a derivative work of the screenplay. He needs a license to do so. This means he would need to pay the required fees.

Bob's work is under copyright, Rob's movie is copyright infringement

### However, movie studios shield themselves by not reading unsolicided scripts

Normally, you can't just send in unsolicited screenplays and gain a case for a movie that comes later. If they arrive, someone puts them into a big old shredder [**and nobody reads it**](https://screencraft.org/blog/10-rules-of-film-tv-industry-etiquette-screenwriters-should-know/#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20Send%20Unsolicited%20Screenplays&text=Some%20will%20even%20send%20hard,accept%20screenplays%20from%20solicited%20sources.). Because nobody at the studio reads them, the studio has no knowledge of the contents. Because there is no knowledge, there is no way they used the contents. Because they had no knowledge and could not use the contents, they couldn't infringe copyright. Any similarities of a screenplay with such an unsolicited text are circumstantial or Scenes a Faire - and not copyright infringement.

See the Zootopia case of [Gary L. Goldman’s Esplanade Productions v Disney](https://www.loeb.com/en/insights/publications/2019/05/esplanade-productions-inc-v-the-walt-disney-company), which was smacked down for he could **not** prove that Disney actually ever read his pitch and used it. In part the case failed because Esplanade never provided what he sent to disney.

See the Rocky case of [Anderson v Stallone](https://Anderson%20v.%20Stallone) in that you can not acquire a copyright in a work by making an unlicensed treatise on an existing franchise made from scenes-a-faire things.

Comment: Why assume that the screenplay was unsolicited? Say Bob first asks if he can send one, and Rob (from my original version of the question) says "okay, send it, I'll take a look). Then, the studio in question doesn't have to follow the etiquette you quoted, they may read unsolicited stuff.

Comment: @Jen I consider it immaterial whether the screenplay send was solicited. Just don't make assumptions either way.

Comment: @Jen _If_ it does make a difference, any assumption would make the answer too narrow. Both cases should be addressed then.

Comment: @Jen the rest of the answer is a frame challenge to the offered hypothetical.

Comment: @Greendrake the solicited/unsolicited script part **is** material. Anderson v Stallone.

Comment: @In [_Anderson v Stallone_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_v._Stallone), the script _itself_ was a copyright infringement because it was a derivative work from the previous Rocky films, that's why the case failed. The notion of solicited/unsolicited in there refers to the _writing_ of the script in the first place (soliciting _from_ the studio), not to peddling it by the author _to_ the studio after it was written.